# Looking for a simple formula to check if a coordinate lies within an annulus sector

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates

I'm building an app which has multiple sections and user needs to click inside the section to choose a "band". It looks like this:
[image: Bands]

I have the co-ordinates of the points: A-J that are marked. I want an equation by which I can determine if a given co-ordinate is inside the given band. Since this image is a hand drawing, it's bad but in the app they are clean [annulus sectors](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=annulus+sector) placed exactly as shown in this image.

Comment: Convert everything to polar coordinates, setting the center of the sectors to be the origin. The formula will become obvious.

Comment: Are the annuli centered at the origin?  Are the coordinates of A-J and the coordinates of the given point polar or cartesian?

Comment: @saulspatz I didn't really understand your first question, mostly because I don't know which is the origin here. These are like concentric circles and I'm trying to determine if a given point in cartesian coordinate like (x,y) lies in Band A, B, C or D. But the points which I do have A to J are in cartesian co-ordinates. All the circles are concentric with differing radii (although in this rough diagram that I drew, I showed lesser curvature than the real case that I'm dealing with)

Comment: If you do not know the origin of the circle, then how do you draw those circular arcs in the first place? It is hard for me to imagine how one could draw (part of) a circle without knowing its center and radius.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to provide a single simple formula, also because you do not show the coordinates of the given points, so I can try to explain a possible procedure to follow.

Supposing you have Cartesian coordinates of your points, write the equation of the straight line through $ADEHJ$ (you only need two points for this), and write the equation of the line through $BCFGI$. The intersection of these lines gives you the center of the annuli, call it $\Omega$, while their slopes can be calculated form the angular coefficients of the lines (remember that $\theta=\arctan(m)$).

Next, calculate the radii of your circular arcs: the bigger radius is $r_1=\overline{A\Omega}=\overline{B\Omega}$, the second bigger is $r_2=\overline{C\Omega}=\overline{D\Omega}$, and so on.

Given the coordinates of a point $P=(x,y)$, to determine where it lays, find its distance from $\Omega$, and compare this with the radii, to see in which annulus it is. Also, the slope of the line through $P$ and $\Omega$ can tell if the point $P$ is between the two sides or if it is too much on the right or on the left.